# How to use login api in loop in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I want to check if statecode is 1 then i get result store in async storage

**API DATA**

```
StatusCode": "1",
        "Message": "Login Successfully",
        "Result": [
            {
                "MemberFirstName": "test",
                "MemberLastName": "test",
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Fetch** in react native

```
 fetch("xyz.com", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => {
                if (result.StatusCode === 1) {
                    console.log("------------",result)
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

In log data of result is not showing

Comment: {
"StatusCode":"1",
"Message":"Login Successfully",
"Result":[{ "MemberFirstName": "test",
            "MemberLastName": "test"}]
}

Answer (score 0):

Api status send "1" (string) , but === checks the equality without type conversion.

```
"1" === 1 //false
"1" == 1 //true
```